# What's the mistake in this JDBC program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

```java
package jdbc;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        int age;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name and age: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        age = sc.nextInt();
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:" +
                                 "//localhost/demo","root","");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            //SQL Query to insert user input
            String sql = "insert into tab values(3,"+name+","+age+");";  
            //Execute INSERT
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            //Dislplay table "tab"
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tab");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2)"+
                                   " " " + rs.getInt(3));
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Enter name and age: 
arpit          //user input
18             //user input
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'arpit' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1535)
    at jdbc.Table.main(Table.java:20)
```

Comment: You have SQL-injection vulnerability. Use PreparedStatement to fix it, it will also fix your current problem.

Comment: the resulting SQL statement you created is like `insert into tab values(3, arpit, 18)` - since it is missing quotes around `arpit`, that is interpreted as a column name. Using single concatenation, as done here, can be a security problem, see [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) or search "SQL injection"

Answer (score 4):

Invalid value entered. Use `PreparedStatement` to set the values in the query. Use column names in the sql which values should be inserted. The primary key is auto generated by default in MySQL, so you don't need to use it. At the end you also don't need to specify the `;`. When statement is executed it automatically adds the closing character.

```java
//SQL Query to insert user input
String sql = "insert into tab(name, age) values(?,?)";  
Statement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);

st.setString(1, name);
st.setInt(2, age);

//Execute INSERT
st.executeUpdate();
```